# Problema con Buttons y TextBox con el Titulo del form

Tags: c#

Tengo un problema con los buttons y un textbox, mi intención es que en un textbox la gente escriba lo que quiera y eso se cambie en el titulo del form pero no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo y lo mismo con los buttons que la gente le de a un button y cambie el titulo del form.

Comment: Comparte lo que hayas logrado hacer hasta el momento, es más fácil dar ayuda a partir de una base que ya tengas que desde cero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No tienes más que cambiar la propiedad Text del formulario por el texto que deseas establecer como título.

Si quieres que el título cambia al cambiar el texto de un TextBox:

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Text = textBox1.Text;
    }
```

Si quieres que cambie al pulsar un botón el código debería estar en el evento Click del botón:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Text = textBox1.Text;
    }
```